# Questions about Affine algebraic group scheme over an infinite field K

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, affine-geometry, affine-schemes

For an easily comprehension of my questions I write some definitions:

*An affine algebraic group scheme over $K$ is a representable group-functor from $K$-algebras category, with a finitely generated representing algebra.*

*An affine algebraic group over a $K$ is an affine algebraic variety with polynomials of definition having coefficients in $K$ equipped with a group structure compatible with the variety structure.*

I know that every affine algebraic group over an infinite $K$ is equivalent to some affine algebraic group scheme over $K$.

I try to show if the converse is true but in my reference i can't read anithing helpful.

Can, some one, give me a hint to show that the converse is true or not?

I try to work with the rispective topologies but i'm confusing about topology over an affine algebraic group scheme. 
If i have $G : \mathcal{Alg}_K \longrightarrow \mathcal{Grp}$ representable with $A=K[X_1, \ldots , X_n]/I$, the isomorphism $G(K) \simeq Hom_K(A,K)$ allow me to equip G(K) with a topology? My intuition is that in some way i can use the Zarisky topology on $\mathbb{A}^n_K$ induced by the algebraic set defined by $I$. It is correct?

Comment: What do you mean by an affine algebraic group? To me the questions seems to be simply the definition.

Comment: For me is an algebraic variety over the algebraic closure of K with a group structure. Where the map defining the group structure are polynomial map.

Comment: If it was only over the algebraic closure of $K$, how could you hope to get something over $K$? Do you require it to be defined over $K$?

Comment: I define as an algebraic variety over  $\overline{K}$ where the coefficients of the polynomials are in $K$

Comment: What is you reference? I recall this being explained in Jantzen's book. The general idea is that either definition is equivalent to having a Hopf algebra structure on the representing algebra (or the coordinate algebra).

Comment: My reference are Milne's note "Basic theory of affine group scheme" and Waterhouse's book "introduction to affine group scheme"

Comment: I'm rusty, but don't you have the obstacle that the functor $G$ is not uniquely determined by $G(K)$ even if $K$ is infinite. We have things like Frobenius kernels that are non-trivial affine algebraic group schemes, but the group is trivial at any field.